# List Title Depends on Variable in Python

Tags: python, list, turtle-graphics

I have just a simple question. Is there a way to do something like:

```
(turtle.pos()) = []
```

so that the turtle's position becomes the title of the list? Or any other way so that a list can be made and the name of it is dependent on the position of the turtle at the time, so that then if the turtle is then back there it can recognize the list linked to that particular location.

Thank you very much. 
C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you should store the mapping in a dictionary:

```
positions = {}
positions[tutle.pos()] = []
```

To check if the turtle ever was in that position, you can do:

```
stuff = positions.get(tutle.pos())
```

This will return `None` if the turtle has never been where it currently is, or the list you put there if the turtle has indeed been there in the past.

---

Objects in Python don't have "names". There are references that point to an object, but the object itself doesn't depend on the names you give it.

I can create a list:

```
list1 = []
```

And give it a few new names:

```
list2 = list1
list3 = list2
```

But this doesn't touch the list at all. It just adds new references to it.

Comment: Interestingly, variables in Python are _supposed_ to be called names or references, to distinguish them from variables that behave in different ways in other languages.

Comment: @user2387370 Calling them references is just as problematic, because (as with variables) references in C++ and the like are completely unlike Python references. If you subscribe to the line of thought that rejects these terms, that is.

Comment: @user2387370 Indeed - although I wanted to avoid specifically using the word "name" here, as this would have made the answer somewhat confusing : ). Objects don't *have* names, but we indeed have names that point to objects.

Comment: Thank you very much. Please excuse my lack of knowledge.

Comment: If you found this answer useful it would be good to accept it (click the big tick beneath the amount of votes it has)